# Get last selected listbox item in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, listbox

I would like to get last selected listbox item (selection mode:multiselect) in javascript. I am working on ms visual studio as web application and need to do it in javascript. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the options and use selected property. Put the script code just before body closing tag, so that html elements get added in DOM before you access them in javascript.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    options = document.getElementById('<%= ddl.ClientID %>').options;
    var lst;
    for(i=0; i < options.length; i++)
      if(options[i].selected)
          lst = options[i].text;
</script>

</body>
```

Edit based on comments

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p2WeG/1/)**

*Html*

```
<select multiple onchange="myFun(this);">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

*Javascript*

```
function myFun(sel)
{    
    alert(sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value);
}
```

Comment: Can you give me an example using a listbox in code? I am pretty new to javascript and dont understand anything from your answer.

Comment: well this gives me tha whole selected items list what i am trying to do is to get the last selected item, Only the last selected item.

Edit:this gives the cronologically last selected. Wont work if selected unorderedly.

Comment: Then you need to use the change event

Comment: Yeah obviously but how?